# Getting Error while creating file in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting error to create a file While used string variable as current time in filename. Error as

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

I couldn't find what is wrong in the code and I tried without "path" variable it will successfully run. I didn't understand what is happening when I used "cTime" variable for create dynamic filename.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\\Reminder_Logs\\";
            string cTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm").Trim();
            using (StreamWriter srRun = File.AppendText(path + "log_Reminder_" + cTime + ".txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(path + "log_Start.txt"))
                {
                    sr.WriteLine("reminder file  created!!! " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can't use colons in the path

Comment: You only need one slash if you use @

Comment: your path should be like: @"C:\Reminder_Logs\"

Comment: but when i remove "cTime" variable then everything ok..

Comment: as suggested by Romano, you must not use colons try this `string cTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm").Trim();`

Comment: Right @Kashi_rock... I got it filename doesn't allow some symbols... Thanks

Comment: you can use "Path.Combine(path + "log_Reminder_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm").Trim() + ".txt");"
in your file.append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that, path contains `:` you can try this

```
string cTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm").Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:` character cannot be used in file name, please use

`string cTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm").Trim();` for example instead.

Answer (score 1):

: char is not accepted in the file path 
path.getinvalidfilenamechars() gives all the invalid chars in the file path